# Handling multiple worksheets of excel with VB6

Tags: excel, vb6

I have an excel file and I would like to edit it in all the sheets with VB6. I would like to make an array of all the names of all the worksheets it has.

Can you help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set xlBook = GetObject("C:\Users\User\Documents\Super.xls")
For each wsheet in xlbook.worksheets
    msgbox wsheet.name
next
```

It's already in a collection so you don't need to put in an array.